# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "_method=DELETE" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Campground"

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I am trying to add a delete route to an express application. this is the code so far

```
{const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const campground = require('./models/campground');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/yelpcamp', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("CONNECTION OPEN!!!")
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("OH NO ERROR!!!!")
        console.log(err)
    });

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))




app.get('/', (req, res) => { res.render('home') });
// app.get('/makeCampground', async (req, res) => {
//     const camp = new campground({
//         title: 'My backyard',
//         description: 'cheap camping!'
//     });
//     await camp.save();
//     res.send(camp);
// });

app.get('/campgrounds', async (req, res) => {
    const campgrounds = await campground.find({});
    res.render('campgrounds/index', { campgrounds });
});

app.get('/campgrounds/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render('campgrounds/new');
});

app.post('/campgrounds', async (req, res) => {
    const camp = await new campground(req.body.campground);
    await camp.save();
    res.redirect('/campgrounds');
});

app.delete('/campgrounds/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    await campground.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    res.redirect('/campgrounds');
});

app.get('/campgrounds/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const foundCampground = await campground.findById(id);
    res.render('campgrounds/show', { foundCampground });
});

app.get('/campgrounds/:id/edit', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const foundCampground = await campground.findById(id);
    res.render('campgrounds/edit', { foundCampground });
});


app.put('/campgrounds/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const campgroundBody = req.body;
    console.log(campgroundBody);
    await campground.findByIdAndUpdate(id, campgroundBody.foundCampground);
    const foundCampground = await campground.findById(id);
    // const campgrounds = await campground.find({});
    res.render('campgrounds/show', { foundCampground });
});


// app.delete('/campgrounds/:id', async (req, res) => {
//     const { id } = req.params;
//     await campground.findByIdAndDelete(id);
//     res.redirect('/campgrounds');
// });


app.listen('3000', () => {
    console.log('Serving on Port 3000');
});
```

I keep getting the cast error you see in the title. I am not sure what is the reason. I tried changing the order of the routes but to no avail

I am not sure what is the reason. I tried changing the order of the routes but to no avail.

Comment: try `new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)`

Comment: Thank you man. I had a problem with a view. I appreciate the time